# Cross compiling a kernel module

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, kernel-module, linux-toolchain

I'm trying to cross compile a helloworld kernel (2.6.x) module for ARM architecture on my intel x86 host.

The codesourcery tool chain for ARM is located at: */home/ravi/workspace/hawk/arm-2009q3*

The kernel source is located at :*/home/ravi/workspace/hawk/linux-omapl1*

My Makefile:

```
ARCH=arm
CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
obj-m := Hello.o
KDIR := /home/ravi/workspace/hawk/linux-omapl1
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
          $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
          $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) clean
```

When i run *make*, the .ko produced is that of my host machine which means the makefile is invoking the native compiler instead of the cross compiler.What am I doing wrong? The cross compiler's binaries are in my path.

Comment: Could we see the Makefile from `KDIR`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Putting `ARCH` and `CROSS_COMPILE` in the Makefile doesn't work. You need to put them on the command line:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
```

Comment: On a side note, can we compile a module without writing a makefile, just by using gcc switches?

Comment: I'm sure you could, but it wouldn't be easy.

Add `V=1` to your commandline when you call make to see how gcc is called. That's what you'd have to type in instead of `make ...`

Comment: As a somehow linux noob I wonder why ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE are in some Makefiles if they don't work that way.

Comment: Instead of command line, It can be exported also either from command line or form makefile

Comment: @itisravi have you tried to compile a module without writing a makefile. i.e just by using gcc

Comment: @AbdulGafoor No, AFAIK, kbuild works only with makefiles.

Answer (score 20):

Replace

> ARCH=arm
>   CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi

by

> export ARCH:=arm
>   export CROSS_COMPILE:=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-

this will also work if you do not want to give these parameter command line each time.

Answer (score 7):

Sidenote: `SUBDIRS=` is deprecated in favor of `M=`.

Answer (score 5):

could you try, you forgot to add ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE into the default and clean

```
ARCH=arm
COMPILER=arm-none-linux-gnueabi
obj-m := Hello.o
KERNELDIR := /home/ravi/workspace/hawk/linux-omapl1
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(COMPILER) modules

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) ARCH=$(ARCH) clean
```

Comment: This is a good answer but there's a typo here. KDIR and KERNELDIR need to be the same variable name.

Comment: @Samuel's remarks also apply to `$CROSS_COMPILE`/`$CROSS`, I believe

Comment: You missed dash and you can use `CROSS_COMPILE` instead of `COMPILER`.

Answer (score 1):

adding `export` at the end of your Makefile variable declarations will make them available to subshells. and add the dash to the `CROSS_COMPILE` prefix as [JayM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290900/jaym) pointed out, and `M` instead of `SUBDIRS` as [user502515](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502515/user502515) answered.

and it's generally a good idea to use `:=` rather than `=` in a Makefile, so the variable only gets interpolated once. really doesn't matter in this particular case though.

```
ARCH := arm
CROSS_COMPILE := arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
obj-m := Hello.o
KDIR := /home/ravi/workspace/hawk/linux-omapl1
PWD := $(shell pwd)
export
default:
          $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
          $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MODULES := hola_kern.o

#guest architecture
ARCH := arm

CROSS_COMPILE := arm-linux-gnueabi-
obj-m := $(MODULES)

#path of the arm compiled kernel
ROOTDIR := /home/aldo/c/proyectos/prefixa/work/kernels/linux-omap-5f0a6e2

MAKEARCH := $(MAKE) ARCH=$(ARCH) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE)

all: modules
modules:
    $(MAKEARCH) -C $(ROOTDIR) M=${shell pwd} modules

clean:
    $(MAKEARCH) -C $(ROOTDIR) M=${shell pwd} clean
```